# Fluent NHibernate: IEnumerable component mapping from a single query?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Hoping you can help me with a mapping problem I have. At the moment I have a view which returns something such as:

Name | Title | Price | Date | Format | FormatPriority |

Example data may be:

Bob | Credits | 340 | 01/01/2010 | BAR | 10 |
Bob | Credits | 340 | 01/01/2010 | FOO | 20 |
Bob | Credits | 340 | 01/01/2010 | WOO | 40 |

What I want is a domain model which looks like this:

string Name; 
string Title;
int Price;
DateTime Date;
IEnumerable Formats;

Format class would then have:

string Type
int Priority

At the moment we are using the ClassMap approach within Fluent NHibernate (not auto config). How would we map this? The Component doesn't seem to support a collection and this isn't a HasMany relationship as it's coming back as part of the same query.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: This is such a huge hack, it pains me to post it.*

This is based on the schema you've provided, so it might need to be modified to accomodate a different design. There probably is a much better way to do this, but hopefully this should get you going again at least.

The issue is you have a bit of a mismatch in your model and query. Your query returns multiple rows which you intend to be for a single entity with multiple components, but NHibernate is geared to interpret that as multiple entities each with a single component.

NHibernate supports collections of components, but only when they're stored in a separate table/view. These components are joined via a foreign key back to the entity table. *If you can change your design to support this, please do so!*

If not, the only option I could think of is a self-join on your view. It won't produce the most optimised query, but it should do the trick.

You didn't mention what your entity was called, so I've gone with `Transaction`.

```
public class Transaction
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Format> Formats { get; set; }
}

public class Format
{
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual int Priority { get; set; }

    // OVERRIDE EQUALITY MEMBERS!
}
```

The mapping I've used is:

```
public class TransactionMap : ClassMap<Transaction>
{
    public TransactionMap()
    {
        Table("vwTransactions");
        Id(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Price);
        Map(x => x.Date);
        HasMany(x => x.Formats)
            .Table("vwTransactions")
            .KeyColumn("Name")
            .Component(c =>
            {
                c.Map(x => x.Type, "Format");
                c.Map(x => x.Priority, "FormatPriority");
            })
            .Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

So you can see the mapping is pointed at the `vwTransactions` view. You didn't specify an id in your schema, so I've used `Name` as a identity (this is important). Skip down to the `HasMany` now, you can see that also points at `vwTransactions`; NHibernate will see this and do a self-join on the view. Then the key column is set to `Name`, the same as the entity Id; this way NHibernate will use that to resolve the references between the component and the entity, rather than trying to use an integer foreign key. The `Fetch.Join` will force NH to eagerly fetch this relationship, so at least we save a bit there. Last thing of note, the `Formats` property is an `ISet`, if you don't do this you'll end up with duplicate components.

If you now create a criteria (or hql) query for `Transaction`, you'll get back your entities with their components; however, you'll get duplicates due to the multiple rows being brought back per entity. This is fairly common, and easily resolved using the DistinctRootEntity transformer.

```
var transactions = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Transaction))
  .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
  .List<Transaction>();
```

That should be it, you'll now end up with just one entity (based on your dataset) with 3 components.

**Nasty, I know.**

Comment: While I'm sure this would have worked, I took you're advice and changed the way the views return data. I now have a view per relationship... hopefully it will work :)